# Unable to save credential for mail channel on Azure

Tags: azure, botframework

I'm trying to register my bot on the email channel.

I got the error "unable to save" or "Unable to validate the given credentials. iD : anId".

If I look in the inspector I got this :

> mBbZ2BiSKVEt.js?compression=gzip2:29 [Microsoft_Azure_BotService]  5:33:57 PM MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter 1 MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter: _errorData: undefined
>   _sourceErrorLevel: undefined
>   baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.AjaxError","MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]
>   code: undefined
>   data: {"type":"POST","requestId":"myId","sessionId":"mySessionId","status":404,"statusText":"error","duration":40.30000000074506}
>   errorLevel: 2
>   errorThrown: 
>   extension: Microsoft_Azure_BotService
>   handled: undefined
>   innerErrors: []
>   jqXHR: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"Cannot POST /api/ClientTrace?defaultCloudName=azure&extensionName=Microsoft_Azure_BotService&pageVersion=1.0.0.32&l=en.en-us&trustedAuthority=portal.azure.com&cacheability=3\n","status":404,"statusText":"error"}
>   message: ajaxExtended call failed
>   name: Error
>   source: undefined
>   stack: null
>   textStatus: error
>   timestamp: 3814640.800000001
>   type: MsPortalFx.Errors.AjaxError

Is this related to my company network or something in azure ? What could I do ?

Thanks in advance

Edit : here is what I got with the github Eric provided :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please try in an incognito window.

Comment: got the same output !

Comment: This repository contains code similar to what is used when saving an email account: https://github.com/EricDahlvang/ExchangeConnectivityTest

Comment: Got it running. At what part should I look?

Comment: The test succeeds. Is there some other information that you need in the console output ?

Comment: The test does not succeed.  It looks like you are getting autodiscovery errors.  Is auto discovery configured?

Comment: It seems there is an interface between azure and office365 in our company (I'm just a trainee and I'm not use to such layers of security).

I will investigate, because it's surely related. Thanks for helping me identifying that. I will post my result asap.

Comment: Got confirmation that autodiscovery can not work in our network.

Comment: We got autodiscovery working and got 200 ok for all test, but we still can't save the credential.

still got Unable to save. Unable to validate the given credentials. ID: "an id" (like the screen in the answer below)

Answer (score 0):

the same problem was bothering me,

I tried,

- onmicrosoft.com
- @hotmail.com
- @outlook.com

domains but no luck. Then I tried my company domain given by Mircosoft and it worked.

It's not a matter of a free Azure subscription, it's about the Office 365 subscription.

Answer (score -1):

> the error "unable to save" or "Unable to validate the given credentials

I can reproduce the issue on my side if I configure Email channel with other email services (not Office 365 email).

[image]

The [Email channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-email) currently works with Office 365 only. Please make sure you are using Office 365 email and entering valid Office 365 credentials.

Besides, similar issue is reported in this github issue:[Configuring the Email Connector to Bot Framework](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1883), you can check it.

Comment: It's an office 365 email. Note that I doesn't have 'Unable to validate" part all the time. It's mostly  'Unable to save' only.

I'm trying to run these tests : https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com but I got some errors. Maye if I manage to got all green it will works.

Comment: I also had >ajax.ts:147 POST https://dev.botframework.com/api/bots/myBot/channels/email 400 (Bad Request)

on the console this morning